# How to modify background color of div based on value contained (with defined min, mean, max values)

Tags: javascript, function, background-color

I'm using a Javascript function to modify the background color of my "content" div based on the value the div contains. Like "conditional formatting" in Excel.

Because the div contains only a discreet variable (possible values 0-100) I'm using an if/else statement to code a different background color for every possible value, 0 to 100. This is obviously a very inefficient solution. In the example below I'm only showing values 0,50,100 for the sake of simplicity.

I'm looking for a solution that allows me to code the background color along a gradient based on 3 defined `hsl` values corresponding to the three `"content"` values I define as the max, mean, and min values.

At `content == 100` I have the div's background color set to `backgroundColor = 'hsl(0,0%,100%)'`. At `content == 0` I have the div's background color set to `backgroundColor = 'hsl(0,0%,0%)'`. (These color values were chosen for the sake of providing a simple example here).

Any ideas?
Here's the fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/cinemologist/rn39fkey/54/

```js
(function () { 
    var content = document.getElementById("content").innerHTML;
    if (content == 100) {
      document.getElementById("content").style.backgroundColor = 'hsl(0,0%,100%)';
    } else if (content == 50) {
      document.getElementById("content").style.backgroundColor = 'hsl(0,0%,50%)';
    } else if (content == 0) {
      document.getElementById("content").style.backgroundColor = 'hsl(0,0%,0%)';
    }
  })();
```

```css
body {
  background-color: rgb(0,20,20);
}

#content {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  color: orange;
  font-size:50px;
  display: flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content: center; 
}
```

```html
<div id="content">0</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just pass the content value into the hsl string you're building. No need for any `if`s except the one checking the min/max allowed values.

```js
(function () { 
    var content = document.getElementById("content").innerHTML;
    if (content <= 100 && content >= 0) {
      document.getElementById("content").style.backgroundColor = 'hsl(0,0%,' + content + '%)';
    } 
  })();
```

```css
body {
  background-color: rgb(0,20,20);
}

#content {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  color: orange;
  font-size:50px;
  display: flex;
  align-items:center;
 justify-content: center; 
 }
```

```html
<div id="content">0</div>
```

Comment: What if I want to set a mean value, so that -- for example -- the hsl values change at a different rate after passing the mean value?

Comment: I guess I'd just use an else statement in that case. Thank you!

Comment: Michael's solution, with my modification here: https://jsfiddle.net/cinemologist/rn39fkey/73/

Comment: Glad my code was able to push you in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
(() => { let div = document.getElementById("Your Div");
div.style.bg = "hsl(0%, 0%," + div.innerHTML + ")";  //Don't know what the actual bb color value is called...  )();
```

Or if you only want 3 color values as in your example, calculate the value by doing:

```
let value = Math.floor(div.innerHTML / 50) * 50;
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea Icy, this looks like a possible solution.